# Como pegar o valor do campo data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um método que retorna valores do banco nos meus componentes da tela. Ele recebe como parâmetro 3 `string` e 2 `DateTime`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.Titulo1.SetaTitulo(Resources.Resource.titulo_cadVideo);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["nIDMedia"]))
        {
            string nIDMedia = Request.QueryString["nIDMedia"];
            Video.PreencheCampos(nIDMedia, txt_descricao.Text, 
                txt_endereco_link.Text, cl_inicio, cl_fim);
            }
        }
    }
```

O problema é que não consigo pegar o valor dos campos de data que são o `cl_inicio` e `cl_fim` que são do tipo Calendar.

Comment: Só com esse trecho de código fica difícil saber o que está acontecendo. Existe algum motivo específico para estas variáveis serem do tipo `Calendar`?

Comment: Sua pergunta ainda não está clara. O problema é: Pegar o valor e mostrar em um campo texto? Pegar o valor e mostrar marcado no calendário? Pegar o valor que o usuário selecionou na tela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use da seguinte forma:

```
Video.PreencheCampos(nIDMedia, txt_descricao.Text, 
    txt_endereco_link.Text, cl_inicio.SelectedDate, cl_fim.SelectedDate);
}
```

[Veja mais sobre o `SelectedDate` aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx).